# how to edit .testsettings in VS 2012

Tags: c#

The .testsettings file that comes with VS 2012 contains out of date browsers (except for IE which is up to date) such as Chrome 2.0 and Firefox 3.0 (can't understand how MS missed those heh heh). But anyway, how can I edit this file and update the browsers and delete the old ones? I'm writing automation scripts using VS 2012 and .webtest file types.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the .testsettings file it's about the VS2012 MTM's future. Sadly you can not update browsers on VS2012 test settings.

VS2015 has great capabilities of testing.

> With Visual Studio and Team Foundation Server 2015 – we are providing Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery solutions in Visual Studio.
>
> As part of Continuous Integration and Delivery, you can create build definitions/release definitions to run automated tests targeting various browsers of in the Build vNext or Release work flow. On the target machine you just need to setup a browser that you would like to target and we will execute tests against the browser – see more details on this blog: http://aka.ms/testingblog.